# Windows Update and Features won't install after moving ProgramData

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

**HUGE UPDATE**

I now figured out why i can't install the `.NET Framework 3.5` and *new* the `Windows DirectPlay` features.

I think this happens because i recently moved a lot of files. I wanted to do all Programs and stuff on my data HDD (F:), and windows running on my SSD (C:). I created those `Symlinks` via `mklink /D`:

> C:\ProgramData → F:\ProgramData
>
> C:\Program Files → F:\Program Files
>
> C:\Program Files (x86) → F:\Program Files (x86)

and, most importantly to the answer below:

> C:\Users\All Users → F:\ProgramData

When i try to install now the features `.NET Framework 3.5` and `DirectPlay` I get the exact same errors as in my old question below.

*Windows Updates* are failing with error code: `0x80070bc9`, Windows Defender with error code: `0x80070643`

How can i make windows update and features work again **without** moving `ProgramData` back to C: drive?

**OLD QUESTION**:

When i try to install the `.NET Framework 3.5`, the installation failures.

**I moved my `ProgramData` folder to another drive recently (I symlinked from `C:` to this drive)**

The Install Error (C:\Windows\Logs\DISM) **update**:
http://scshot.deepspace.onl/eff24e62-f2b6-431f-a280-821d48554f6e.log

The CBS (C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.txt) (only this file because it's the only one which was changed today) http://scshot.deepspace.onl/6d071d59-f6cf-4da5-a753-38f29a31150d.log

[image]

> C:\Windows\system32>Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
>
> Tool for image management
>   Version: 10.0.10586.0
>
> Features will be activated
>   [==========================100.0%==========================]
>
> Error: 3017
>
> The requested procedure failed. A system restart is required to revert the changes.
>
> The DISM-Protokollis here: "C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log".

Comment: Please [edit] and translate the error messages to English.

Comment: @DavidPostill everything Important translated

Comment: [Adding features (including .NET 3.5) to Windows 10](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/08/31/adding-features-including-net-3-5-to-windows-10/) suggests a different command line to install it.

Comment: the error shows that there is a pending operation. Have you made a reboot?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Operation failed

Comment: @DavidPostill does not work...

Comment: what fails? The reboot? The configuration of the pending updates?

Comment: @magicandre1981 The install task fails, nothing more is written there, more info in the Log. I can't understand the log...

Comment: have you done the reboot or not?

Comment: @magicandre1981 sure, but the reboot just resets my PC as it was before. Nothing changed.

Comment: boot to the recovery options, open cmd and run **DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\** Does this revert any pending changes?

Comment: @magicandre1981 no, this doesn't change anything

Comment: share the complete folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS so that I can see in detail what fails

Comment: @magicandre1981 done

Comment: Try to move your ProgramData folder back and boot. If no improvement, do "sfc /scannow". It would help to know your Windows version.

Comment: @harrymc Win 10 Version 1511 Build 10586.164

Comment: the log also only shwos that a reboot is required. Run regedit, go to HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing and look if there is an entry **RebootPending** If yes, backup the key and delete/rename it. Now try to run the DISM command

Comment: @magicandre1981 nothing there..

Comment: Have you tried moving your `Temp` directory to your hdd? (`Win+Pause/Break -> Advanced Sys Settings -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables`, both User and System variables. I do a `D:\TEMP` on my machine.)  If you've made any registry changes, have you run your 64-bit version of Regedit, and all of your changes present?

Comment: For `Program Files` (and `(x86)`), I recommend leaving them on your `C:` drive and simply changing your default installation directories in registry to your hdd.  Some programs will still demand space in `C:\Program Files` even if it's installed off the system drive (I think Visual Studio does).  Here, again, I think you'll need to do this in 32- and 64-bit Regedits: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir' and 'ProgramFilesDir (x86)`. If you go that route, at least you won't have to remember to change the install directory every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation errors after moving folders like these to other drives are inevitable.  I used to do it for years, and I simply learned to live with some updates' not being installed.  Part of the issue may be that the `All Users` folder is a symlink to `ProgramData`.  Somehow or another, Windows may be finding issue with this, which wouldn't be surprising.

Things I would try either individually or in combination with each other (after backing up your drive):

1. Recreate the `All Users` symlink:

   - Delete the `c:\users\All Users` symlink
   - Create a new `c:\users\All Users` symlink to the new `ProgramData`
2. Search through the registry for `c:\users\All Users' values and change them to your new folder.
3. Download the .NET update executable and install it (if it has a .exe extension, just double-click it.  *.msu files require wusa.exe).

Comment: Unluckly this doesn't work, i thought it would. I updated the question because of your answer. Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 3):

This may not solve the problem, but here is some advice.

First it is my experience that moving major Windows folders is problematic
for Windows Update. In case of need, one should only move specific sub-folders,
rather than the entire folder.

Second, the first error I see in the DISM log is :

```
2016-06-11 18:04:34, Info   DISM  DISM Package Manager: PID=9044 TID=7848 CBS session options=0x20100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2016-06-11 18:04:38, Info   DISM  DISM Package Manager: PID=9044 TID=5548  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x80070bc9) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2016-06-11 18:04:38, Error  DISM  DISM Package Manager: PID=9044 TID=7848 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80070bc9)
2016-06-11 18:04:38, Error  DISM  DISM Package Manager: PID=9044 TID=7848 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x80070bc9)
2016-06-11 18:04:38, Error  DISM  DISM Package Manager: PID=9044 TID=7848 Failed ProcessChanges. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x80070bc9)
2016-06-11 18:04:39, Error  DISM  DISM Package Manager: PID=9044 TID=7848 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070bc9)
2016-06-11 18:04:39, Info   DISM  DISM Package Manager: PID=9044 TID=7848 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2016-06-11 18:04:39, Error  DISM  DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80070BC9
```

The error code 0x80070bc9 is typical of Windows Update errors.
This error means "the request operation failed, a system reboot is required to roll back changes made".

My recommendations are (reboot and recheck after each step) :

1. Return the ProgramData folder back to its place
2. Run the `sfc /scannow` command to verify system integrity as [described here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html)
3. Run the command

`fsutil resource setautoreset true c:\`

Then in [Safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode) try to delete these files from the Command Prompt (cmd):

```
cd %SystemRoot%\System32\SMI\Store\Machine
attrib -s -h *
del *.blf
del *.regtrans-ms
cd %SystemRoot%\System32\config\TxR
attrib -s -h *
del /q *
```

4. Run the [Windows Update troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-update-troubleshooter)
5. Last resort : Run a non-destructive re-installation (aka in-place upgrade) of Windows. This will keep your personal files and settings, installed drivers, programs and apps, and may return Windows to a fully working state. This method usually helps when nothing else resolves a Windows Update error.
   See the article
   [Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Before starting, I recommend taking good backups.
It is best to also take a snapshot image of the system disk and ensure
you can restore it when booting from CD or USB.
[AOMEI Backupper Standard Freeware](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) is my recommended backup utility
with its recovery boot CD / USB.

Comment: I tried everything, except moving ProgramData. My question is how to manage this with ProgramData moved. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You should move back ProgramData and then selectively move out  and symlink some folders, but not the Windows ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Windows Update instead of your install source,

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482065.aspx

> If you select Contact Windows Update directly to download repair
>   content instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS), any attempt
>   to add features (for example, .NET Framework 3.5) or repair the
>   feature file store, uses Windows Update to download files. Target
>   computers require Internet and Windows Update access for this option.

You will change this value in local system policies `gpedit.msc`

> Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates
>   -> System -> Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair

And enable `Contact Windows Update directly`

http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/21919-windows-update-error-0x80080005.html

This GPO enables Windows to use Windows Update to download missing installation files. You can then try to install using Control Panel, add features.

Comment: Still a failure

Comment: As I see your update I rather believe that the answer would be: no, it is not possible. But updating your question by changing it quite substantially is usually not advisable. If you find a solution, I would be surely interested what it was.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this online:

Hello!

It might be a bit late, but i answer anyway.

My setup is probably exactly the same as yours.

> C:\Program Files\ and C:\Program Files (x86)\ are symbolic links to
>   P:\Program Files\ and P:\Program Files (x86)\ in my case

and i had the exact same issue with error 0x80070011 trying to install .NET 3.5.
Well, i actually managed to install it with this little "trick":
Regedit -> `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion`

Now change the Path in

> ProgramFilesDir
>   ProgramFilesDIr (x86) and
>   ProgramW6432Dir  to (in my case) Drive P:\

install .NET 3.5 and change back the paths afterwards.
Restart your computer and everything should be fine :)

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8a864e4f-9e18-435b-9404-2feab9057f15/cannot-install-net-framework-on-symlinked-drive