# Windows 10 update from 1803 to 1909 fails

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My Windows 10 repeatedly fails to update. Today I decided to make a day of getting it to upgrade - and after a day of installing I'm no better off.

The Windows Update tool fails and rolls back with no explanation, so I downloaded the ISO, mounted it, and ran setup.exe from a Windows session.

It ran until 85%, then rolled back, giving the error:

```
0xC1900101 - 0c4000D
The installation failed in the SECOND_BOOT phase with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation
```

I checked C:\Windows\Panther\NewOs\Panther\setuperr.log and found the following, which I don't understand:

```
2020-02-07 15:15:22, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #10# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = 990 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup'), vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-02-07 15:15:22, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #9# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:31]'\Registry\Machine\SYSTEM\Setup\', vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
﻿2020-02-07 15:15:24, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1253): Result = 0xC1800104[gle=0x00000002]
2020-02-07 15:15:24, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::CheckUserInterruptEx(3060): Result = 0x800704D3
2020-02-07 15:15:24, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::CheckUserInterrupt(3112): Result = 0x800704D3
2020-02-07 15:15:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(794): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-02-07 15:15:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(392): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-02-07 15:15:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(284): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-02-07 15:15:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(420): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupResponseTemplate<class IDlpResponse>::OnCancel(238): Result = 0x800704C7
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupResponseTemplate<class IDlpResponse>::ExecuteRoutine(143): Result = 0x800704C7
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpResponseImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IDlpResponse> > > >::Execute(1923): Result = 0x800704C7
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class ICompatAction> > > >::ExecuteResponse(1365): Result = 0x800704C7
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionCompat::ExecuteSysReqScan(806): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionCompat::ExecuteRoutine(635): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class ICompatAction> > > >::Execute(493): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteAction(3300): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteActions(3454): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Execute(1631): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2582): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2545): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(786): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:34, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(392): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:36, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Cancel(982): Result = 0xC1800104[gle=0x00000003]
2020-02-07 15:15:36, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Cancel(986): Result = 0xC180010A[gle=0x00000003]
2020-02-07 15:15:36, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Cancel(982): Result = 0xC1800104[gle=0x00000003]
2020-02-07 15:15:36, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(284): Result = 0xC1900201
2020-02-07 15:15:36, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(420): Result = 0xC1900201
```

I've also tried DISM, but that failed with

```
Error: 0x80080005
DISM failed. No operation was performed.
```

The DISM log errors near the end:

```
DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SetupPlatformManager
2020-02-07 17:20:10, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: SetupPlatformManager.
2020-02-07 17:20:10, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Processing the top level command token(cleanup-image). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2020-02-07 17:20:10, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2020-02-07 17:20:10, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2020-02-07 17:20:10, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 CBS session options=0x40100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2020-02-07 17:25:50, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80080005)
2020-02-07 17:25:50, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x80080005)
2020-02-07 17:25:50, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x80080005)
2020-02-07 17:25:50, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80080005)
2020-02-07 17:25:50, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=22844 TID=21284 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2020-02-07 17:25:50, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80080005
```

The CBS.log referenced by DISM has many of these:

```
 2020-02-07 17:25:19, Info                  CBS    Failed to create CBS worker - waiting for a second and trying again [HRESULT = 0x80080005]
```

Can anyone help decipher these logs and point me to what is preventing Windows from upgrading?

General stats:

- Win 10 Pro
- 32 GB Ram
- i9-7900X
- Windows installed to a 476GB SSD with
  36GB free

Comment: [Windows 10 update: 0xC1900101 - 0x3000D, FIRST\_BOOT and MIGRATE\_DATA](https://superuser.com/questions/1175497/windows-10-update-0xc1900101-0x3000d-first-boot-and-migrate-data)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1084452/windows-update-and-features-wont-install-after-moving-programdata/1090379#1090379)  You need to disconnect any perpetual devices connect to your system.  The version of Windows 10 you are upgrading from had this issue if any external devices were connected when the upgrade happened[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1182584/windows-10-upgrade-to-version-1607-keeps-failing)

Comment: If none of the related or possible duplicates solutions work, perform a Windows Update reset, this will clear out the Windows Update cache.  Using the Disk Cleanup utility to remove any previous attempts is also helpful.  Failing all of that, download Windows 10 version 1809, and try upgrading to that.  Edit your question to include all vital information.

Comment: What's is your exact Windows build number?

Comment: Sounds like hardware or Driver incompatibility, disconnect any necessary hardware before upgrade, if there is a wireless card remove it just before upgrade, If you have 3rd party Anti Virus installed, uninstall it completely.